# xhci_hcd errors on CentOS 6 for cp210x device

Tags: centos6, kernel, drivers, usb, serial

We have very old `CentOS 6` installed on `CheckWay Sherman` with Linux kernel `2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.i686`.

We try to integrate external usbserial *scales* device but there are errors settings `UART` speed.

```
stty -f /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
error unable to perform operation
```

Here are relevant messages from `dmesg`:

```
cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
cp210x 2-3:1.0: device disconnected
usb 2-4: new full speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-4: Product: CP2102N USB to UART Bridge Controller
usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 52add1d6cbd5eb11ac3ffdf743d319e3
usb 2-4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
cp210x 2-4:1.0: cp210x converter detected
usb 2-4: reset full speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Setup ERROR: setup context command for slot 6.
usb 2-4: reset full speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Setup ERROR: setup context command for slot 6.
usb 2-4: reset full speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep c1b5d540
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep c1b5d56c
usb 2-4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

`udev` configuration:

```
[root@pos_test_disp ~]# grep -r "usb" /etc/modprobe.d/
/etc/modprobe.d/dist.conf:alias char-major-188-* usbserial
/etc/modprobe.d/dist.conf:alias usbdevfs usbcore
/etc/modprobe.d/dist.conf:install usbmouse /sbin/modprobe --first-time --ignore-install usbmouse && { /sbin/modprobe hid; /bin/true; }
/etc/modprobe.d/dist.conf:remove usbmouse { /sbin/modprobe -r hid; } ; /sbin/modprobe -r --first-time --ignore-remove usbmouse
/etc/modprobe.d/dist.conf:alias usb-uhci uhci-hcd
/etc/modprobe.d/dist.conf:alias usb-ohci ohci-hcd
[root@pos_test_disp ~]# grep -r "cp210x" /etc/modprobe.d/
```

`lsusb`:

```
[root@pos_test_disp ~]# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/11p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=cp210x, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 1, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
```

`lsmod`:

```
[root@pos_test_disp ~]# lsmod | head
Module                  Size  Used by
cp210x                 11320  1
usbserial              30508  3 cp210x
```

I tried to connect the device to another port, rebooting the system etc...

Do you thing I need try to recompile drivers and put there debug logging?

If so, do I need to dig into `cp210x` or `xhci_hcd`?

Or may be there is some known solution?

> PS: I know that we need to upgrade owr hardware, but unfortunately there is no such possibility.

**UPDATE**

I updated the system to kernel `2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.centos.plus.i686` with `yum update` but the problem is still stay.